# C++ proper way to static_cast

Tags: c++, exception, casting, static-cast

`static_cast`will not throw an exception. But if it does not succeed, it will produce a undefined result. What is the most proper way to check whether the cast succeeded?

Will this help?

```
NewType new_typ_obj = static_cast<NewType>(obj); 

if (new_typ_obj)
    new_typ_obj.do();
```

Comment: Proper way of static casting is **DON'T** (cast at all).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[static_cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c36yw7x9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) does not give you information about success.  If you need to do dynamic type casting use dynamic_cast or a library like boost any.

Answer (score 7):

In the example you give, that `static_cast` *could* throw an exception depending on the types involved, for example if the constructor of `NewType` throws. If there doesn't exist any conversion chain from the type of `obj` to `NewType`, then it won't even compile.

You may be thinking of using `static_cast` to convert a pointer-to-base into a pointer-to-derived, which is the case that `dynamic_cast` checks. There's no way to tell whether `static_cast` succeeds in that case. It's your responsibility as the programmer to only use it if it's correct.

Answer (score 4):

A `static_cast` only has undefined behaviour when you are casting between pointer, reference, or pointer to member types. It occurs when you perform a downcast to a type that is not truly the type of the object pointed at.

In your example, unless `NewType` is a typedef of a pointer or reference type and `obj` is also of those types, the compiler will give you an error if the cast is invalid.

Performing `if (new_typ_obj)` does not make sense for checking whether the cast was successful in any `static_cast` case. If `NewType` is not one of these polymorphic types, then using `new_type_obj` as a condition only works if you have some way to convert it to `bool` (or it *is* `bool`). Even if it does, it has nothing to do with the cast. If instead you are `static_cast`ing through pointers to an inheritance hierarchy, then `static_cast` will not give you any information about whether it succeeded. For that, you want `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 1):

`static_cast` will not compile if the type you want to cast **is not related** to the type you want to cast into. Except with `void *` that is related to all types. Thus static_cast is still a great assurance, at compile time.

There is still the danger of doing a wrong downcast.

My personal rule is to:

- prefer using static_cast for upcast, ( show the intent )
- prefer using dynamic_cast for downcast, and checking the returned value.

The latter rule can be done away with if the static_cast for a downcast is dangerless.

Comment: Be aware that "always used `dynamic_cast` for down cast" only works if the base class is always polymorphic. So it's dependent on another style rule, "only upcast to polymorphic bases". That second rule makes sense in a lot of projects but not *necessarily* all.

Comment: @SteveJessop but if the base class isnt polymorphic, dynamic_cast will just return nullptr . ( of course it doesn't make much sense to use it )

Comment: “alway use `dynamic_cast` for downcasting” is just wrong. There are legitimate cases where you know at compile time that the cast *will* succeed and *you should make that assumption explicit* by using `static_cast`. Not doing this is objectively bad.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have edited "always" to "prefer". Does it still feel so wrong ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland I can live with that.

Comment: @SteveJessop with polymorphic class, it is to understand base class with more than one child class ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland how to you do check after `dynamic_cast` ? is there a way to do it that, for sure, will work anytime anywhere ?

Comment: @antitrust at runtime, `dynamic_cast<>` returns `nullptr` if ever the downcast is incorrect. so you just compare the value of your pointer if it is NULL/nullptr.

Comment: @antitrust: a polymorphic base class means one that has at least one `virtual` function. It doesn't matter how many derived classes it has, although the name anticipates that it can have many.